# A question related to HTMLInputElement of attribute type='date' and its Native Date Picker

Tags: javascript, html, html-input

Lets say we have a simple input tag:

```
    <input type="text" />
```

In the moment that its type attribute is changed to date, the input element modify its behaviour by adding a native date picker field which varies from browser to browser.

My question is: how this event of adding a native date picker works?
Is there a way to get access to this object using Javascript?

Comment: Its not really "adding", the element is simply re-rendered for that type by the browser.  The only object you have access to is the [input DOM object](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#the-input-element) and whatever properties/functions it exposes/uses for that type (min,max,step,etc).

Answer (score 0):

No.

HTMLInputElements have internal state dictated by the `type` attribute. Whereas other elements are descendants of other prototypes( or `classes` ) there is no way to adjust the prototype of an HTMLInputElement based on its type before creation,  though you may choose to extend or adjust that prototype yourself to include additional, type-specific functionality and create an input element based on that prototype/class and not its parent, HTMLInputElement

Furthermore, this isn't unusual. You aren't able to adjust anything that utilizes native, internal functionality in the host browser. A.e. things like alert, prompt, and file dialogs are completely out of control for the developer.

Comment: How can I get access to the internal state of the HTMLInputElement? Is there a way of being able to implement my own type of number picker feature?

Comment: @ViníciusNobre no,  it's not accessible. And yes, of course you can cobble together your own code-based pseudo-input. There are tons of libraries that do that like select2

Comment: Okay. Thank you very much.